Is there any way to optimize the loading of items (layout) in a RecyclerView?
I know that coroutines help with the data in the RecyclerView, but my problem is not the data, because the item inside the recycler don't use images or database, my problem is the layout i am using, I tried using the Android EditText instead of the Material Design ones and simplifying the entire layout, and it works! But it looks quite ugly, and I want to use this layout.. On mid-range and low-end phones, this layout throws the error:
Skipped 105 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/dataNameLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:hint="Data Name"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/dataValueLayout">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/dataName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/dataValueLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            app:placeholderText="300 500 200 700 ..."
            android:hint="Data Value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dataNameLayout"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/dataValue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:digits="0123456789. "
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonColor"
            style="?attr/materialIconButtonFilledStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:icon="@drawable/palette_icon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/deleteTextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deleteTextView"
            style="?attr/materialIconButtonFilledStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            app:icon="@drawable/delete_icon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/buttonColor" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


class AdapterRecycler(private var dataList: List<Data>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    fun updateList(newList: List<Data>){
        val colorsDiff = ItemsDiffUtil(dataList, newList)
        val result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(colorsDiff)
        dataList = newList
        result.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = dataList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val itemPosition = dataList[position]

        val textData = itemPosition.title
        holder.dataNameEditText.setText(textData)

    }
}

